# Loading changing columns in Apache Hive

Tags: hive

I have a HIVE table, partitioned on date field and gets loaded every day. We got a request to add a new column at the end and load the data into the same HIVE table. Are there any better ways to handle this column change requests in keeping the existing data.

Do I need to delete the data in the existing table and recreate the table using the new columns and load the data.

Answer (score 0):

In which format do you save the data?
If you are using avro-format, just add the new fields in the .avsc-filed and set a default-value:

```
{
 "name": "yourData",
 "type": ["string", "null"],
 "default": "null"
```

}

If you store the data as csv, then it seems to be a little bit more complicated.
Changing the table with alter table didn't worked in my case (I have no idea why).
So I deleted the table, recreated it with the new columns and added the partitions and it works.
Make shure that your table is an **external** Table, then you don't have to delete the data.

eg:

```
Old Data:
889,5CE1,2016-07-25

New Data:
900,5DCBA,2016-07-25,2012-03-22,152047
```

hive:

```
create table somData (
anid int
,astring String
,extractDate date
)
PARTITIONED BY(cusPart STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TextFile location "/your/location";
```

what you have to do:

```
ALTER TABLE somData  SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE');

drop table somData;

create table somData (
anid int
,astring String
,extractDate date
,anotherDate date
,someInt int
)
PARTITIONED BY(cusPart STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TextFile location "/your/location";

ALTER TABLE someData ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (cusPart='foo') LOCATION '/your/paritioned/data';
```